# Member Data of Class not updating

Tags: c++

I am trying to program a NFL season simulator in C++, and while doing so, I ran into a problem when trying to update the team records.

My code is as follows:

**team.h**

```
class Team
{
    public:

    // Team Data Fields 
    std::string teamName; // Team's Name
    int teamRating;  // Team's Rating
    int winOrLose;   // The result of the game: 1 - Win, 0 - Loss.
    int totalWins;   // Total Wins
    int totalLosses; // Total Losses

    // Class Constructors
    Team ();
    Team (std::string teamName);

    // Member functions definitions:
    void updateTeamRating();
    std::string teamRecord();
};

Team::Team()
{
    teamName = "Void";
    teamRating = 50;
    winOrLose = 0;
    totalWins = 0;
    totalLosses = 0;
}

Team::Team(std::string inputTeamName)
{
    teamName = inputTeamName;
    teamRating = 50;
    winOrLose = 0;
    totalWins = 0;
    totalLosses = 0;
}

void Team::updateTeamRating()
{
    if (winOrLose == 1)
    {
        teamRating = teamRating + 5;
        totalWins++;
    }
    else if (winOrLose == 0)
    {
        totalLosses++;
        teamRating = teamRating - 5;
        if (teamRating <= 0)
        {
            teamRating = 5;
        }
    }
}

std::string Team::teamRecord()
{
    return teamName + std::string(" (") + std::to_string(totalWins) + std::string("-") +
        std::to_string(totalLosses) + std::string(")"); 
}
```

**div.h**

```
class Divison
{
    public:

    std::string divName;

    // 4 Teams in a Divison
    Team team1;
    Team team2;
    Team team3;
    Team team4;

    Divison();
    Divison(Team one, Team two, Team three, Team four, std::string givenDivName);

    void game(Team team1, Team team2);
    void runRegDivSeason();

    Team playoffTeam();
    std::string toString();
};

Divison::Divison()
{
}

Divison::Divison(Team one, Team two, Team three, Team four, std::string givenDivName)
{
    team1 = one;
    team2 = two;
    team3 = three;
    team4 = four;
    divName = givenDivName;
}

void Divison::game(Team team1, Team team2)
{
    int totalRating = team1.teamRating + team2.teamRating;
    //cout << totalRating << endl;
    int result = (rand() % totalRating) + 1;
    if (result <= team1.teamRating)
    {
        team1.winOrLose = 1;
        team2.winOrLose = 0;
        team1.updateTeamRating();
        team2.updateTeamRating();
        std::cout << "Winner: " + team1.teamRecord() + " Loser: " + team2.teamRecord() + ".\n" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        team1.winOrLose = 0;
        team2.winOrLose = 1;
        team1.updateTeamRating();
        team2.updateTeamRating();   
        std::cout << "Winner: " + team2.teamRecord() + " Loser: " + team1.teamRecord() + ".\n" << std::endl;
    }

}

void Divison::runRegDivSeason()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        game(team1, team2);
        game(team1, team3);
        game(team1, team4);
        game(team2, team3);
        game(team2, team4);
        game(team3, team4);
    }
}

std::string Divison::toString()
{
    return divName + ":\n   " + team1.teamRecord() + "\n    "
        +  team2.teamRecord() + "\n " +  team3.teamRecord() + "\n   "
        +  team4.teamRecord() + "\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

#include "team.h"
#include "div.h"



int main()
{
    Team Boston = Team("New England Patriots");
    Team Buffalo = Team("Buffalo Bills");
    Team NYJ = Team("New York Jets");
    Team Miami = Team("Miami Dolphins");
    Divison AFCE = Divison(Boston, Buffalo, NYJ, Miami, "AFC East");
    AFCE.runRegDivSeason();
    std::cout << AFCE.toString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run program, I want something like:

```
C:\myfiles\mfl>test
Winner: New England Patriots (1-0) Loser: Buffalo Bills (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (1-1).

Winner: New England Patriots (2-1) Loser: Miami Dolphins (0-1).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (1-1) Loser: New York Jets (1-1).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (1-1) Loser: Buffalo Bills (1-2).

Winner: New York Jets (2-1) Loser: Miami Dolphins (1-2).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (2-2) Loser: New England Patriots (2-2).

Winner: New York Jets (3-1) Loser: New England Patriots (2-3).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (2-2) Loser: New England Patriots (2-4).

Winner: New York Jets (4-1) Loser: Buffalo Bills (2-3).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (3-3) Loser: Miami Dolphins (2-3).

Winner: New York Jets (5-1) Loser: Miami Dolphins (2-4).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (3-3) Loser: New England Patriots (2-5).

Winner: New England Patriots (3-5) Loser: New York Jets (6-2).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (3-4) Loser: New England Patriots (3-6).

Winner: New York Jets (7-2) Loser: Buffalo Bills (3-4).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (4-4) Loser: Buffalo Bills (3-5).

Winner: New York Jets (8-2) Loser: Miami Dolphins (4-5).

Winner: New England Patriots (4-6) Loser: Buffalo Bills (3-6).

Winner: New England Patriots (5-6) Loser: New York Jets (8-3).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (5-5) Loser: New England Patriots (4-7).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (4-6) Loser: New York Jets (8-4).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (5-6) Loser: Miami Dolphins (5-6).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (6-6) Loser: New York Jets (8-5).

AFC East:
        New England Patriots (4-7)
        Buffalo Bills (5-6)
        New York Jets (8-5)
        Miami Dolphins (6-6)


C:\myfiles\mfl>
```

But I get:

```
C:\myfiles\mfl>test
Winner: New England Patriots (1-0) Loser: Buffalo Bills (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (0-1).

Winner: New England Patriots (1-0) Loser: Miami Dolphins (0-1).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (1-0) Loser: New York Jets (0-1).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (1-0) Loser: Buffalo Bills (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: Miami Dolphins (0-1).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (0-1).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: Buffalo Bills (0-1).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (1-0) Loser: Miami Dolphins (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: Miami Dolphins (0-1).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (0-1).

Winner: New England Patriots (1-0) Loser: New York Jets (0-1).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: Buffalo Bills (0-1).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (1-0) Loser: Buffalo Bills (0-1).

Winner: New York Jets (1-0) Loser: Miami Dolphins (0-1).

Winner: New England Patriots (1-0) Loser: Buffalo Bills (0-1).

Winner: New England Patriots (1-0) Loser: New York Jets (0-1).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (1-0) Loser: New England Patriots (0-1).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (1-0) Loser: New York Jets (0-1).

Winner: Buffalo Bills (1-0) Loser: Miami Dolphins (0-1).

Winner: Miami Dolphins (1-0) Loser: New York Jets (0-1).

AFC East:
        New England Patriots (0-0)
        Buffalo Bills (0-0)
        New York Jets (0-0)
        Miami Dolphins (0-0)


C:\myfiles\mfl>
```

As far as I can tell, this indicates that `totalWins` and `totalLosses` variables of each object is reset to 0 after every game, which I cannot find the reason for. All of the debugging that I have done indicates that the process goes exactly how I want it to, with the exception of the reset. I would greatly appreciate any insight on why this occurs.

Comment: "_All of the debugging that I have done indicates that the process goes exactly how I want it to, with the exception of the reset._" Didn't such debugging session indicate, that the `Division` member variables didn't change during the execution of `game`? Those variables are not "reset", they are simply not changed, due to you doing modifications on copies of those objects. Pass by reference, instead of by value, if you want to modify those objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass variables as references or pointers if you want to modify their properties.
Didn't tested, but try:

```
Divison::Divison(Team& one, Team& two, Team& three, Team& four, std::string givenDivName)
```

Or

```
Divison::Divison(Team* one, Team* two, Team* three, Team* four, std::string givenDivName)
```

and call example with pointers:

```
Divison AFCE = Divison(&Boston, &Buffalo, &NYJ, &Miami, "AFC East");
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor `Divison(Team one, Team two, Team three, Team four, std::string givenDivName)` creates a copy of the teams thus the original object won't be changed. Take references as @Dimitry K. suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the "team1 , team2 , team3 and team4 variables as pointers" in div and assigning the address to those pointers in the constructor of div .

Comment: As this question is tagged C++, using references would be more idiomatic.